# How does majority algorithm works in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, spatial-analyst, resampling

I'm trying to understand how does the majority resampling works in ArcGIS, they write that

"The MAJORITY option, which performs a majority algorithm, determines the new value of the cell based on the most popular values within the filter window. It is mainly used with discrete data just as the nearest neighbor method; Majority tends to give a smoother result than Nearest."

I am talking about the [Majority Filter](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Majority_Filter/009z00000037000000/) geoprocessing tool from Spatial Analyst extension.

What if there are two most popular values?

Is there a way to resample a raster if for example 50% is covered by a value?

Comment: Majority uses the neighboring cells to determine the most common value. http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//009z00000037000000 Also it may return NoData in the case of a tie. I'm sure this question has been asked here before.

Answer (score 3):

[**Per documentation:**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Smoothing_zone_edges_with_Boundary_Clean_and_Majority_Filter/009z0000003s000000/GUID-CBD68932-69B7-469B-9DCB-8A743B72B908/)

> If these criteria are not met, no replacement occurs, and the cell
>   retains its value.

So if MAJORITY OR HALF conditions are not met, then the cell value will not change. It will not change to NoData, It will only keep its original value.