# How does majority resampling technique works in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, resampling

I would like to understand how does the majority resampling technique works.

To be specific the documentation below states that the method will use a 4X4 filter and will populate the output with the maximum count of pixels found.

- https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/resample.htm

**If it finds 8 cells of agricultural land cover and 8 cells of roads in the 4X4 filter window, what will be the output data set?**

I did find a similar question, but the comment and answer are contradicting, and not sure if the output will remain the same or will change to NoData? [How does majority algorithm works in ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162333/how-does-majority-algorithm-works-in-arcgis)

Any theory on this would be great, and if we have any supporting document that can explain this in a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After in-depth testing, I can confirm that if the majority filter hits a situation where there is an equal division of classified cells found in the filter.

As an output, there will be no change observed and the resampled output will be similar to the input grid.

The workflow followed to test this out is shared below:

**The original study grid(4X4)**

[image]

**Unsupervised Classification**

[image]

**Clipped output to the AOI(Showing equal division of 2 classes)**

[image]

**Final result(No change)**

[image]